# Setting and changing SQLite database password in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm implementing SQLite functionality in my code, where I can create an SQLite database file and communicate with it. I can't, however, password protect it. I've seen a lot of solutions, for example:

```cs
conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
conn.ChangePassword("Password");
```

However, the methods ChangePassword() or SetPassword() doesn't exist in System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, so it won't work. So my question is, am I missing something?

I'm using the latest release of the official SQLite Nuget Package.

Comment: Do you have a .net Core project? It's not there in .net Core, but it is there in .net Framework projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is not supported in the .net Core (.net Standard) version of the library.

For connecting to a password-protected database, specify the password in the connection string. Use the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.Password` or `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder.HexPassword` properties.

For setting a password or changing the password, issue an sql `pragma` statement.

```
pragma key='NewPassword'
```

or

```
pragma rekey='NewPassword'
```

For details see [Using the "key" PRAGMA](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki)

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! you're a life saver!